# Entity Framework: Count() very slow on large DbSet and complex WHERE clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to perform a count operation on this Entity Framework (EF6) data set using a relatively complex expression as a `WHERE` clause and expecting it to return about 100k records.

The count operation is obviously where records are materialized and therefore the slowest of operations to take place. The count operation is taking about 10 seconds in our production environment which is unacceptable.

Note that the operation is performed on the DbSet directly (db being the Context class), so no lazy loading should be taking place.

How can I further optimize this query in order to speed up the process?

The main use case is displaying an index page with multiple filter criteria but the the function is also used for writing generic queries to the `ParcelOrders`table as required for other operations in the service classes which might be a bad idea resulting in very complex queries resulting from laziness and might potentially be a future problem.
The count is later used for pagination, and a much smaller number of records (e.g. 500) is actually displayed. This is a database-first project using SQL Server.

`ParcelOrderSearchModel` is a C#-class that serves to encapsualte query parameters and is used exclusively by service classes in order to call the `GetMatchingOrders`function.
Note that on the majority of calls, the majority of the parameters of `ParcelOrderSearchModel` will be null.

```
public List<ParcelOrderDto> GetMatchingOrders(ParcelOrderSearchModel searchModel)
{
        // cryptic id known --> allow public access without login
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.KeyApplicationUserId) && searchModel.ExactKey_CrypticID == null)
            throw new UnableToCheckPrivilegesException();

        Func<ParcelOrder, bool> userPrivilegeValidation = (x => false);

        if (searchModel.ExactKey_CrypticID != null)
        {
            userPrivilegeValidation = (x => true);
        }
        else if (searchModel.KeyApplicationUserId != null)
            userPrivilegeValidation = privilegeService.UserPrivilegeValdationExpression(searchModel.KeyApplicationUserId);

        var criteriaMatchValidation = CriteriaMatchValidationExpression(searchModel);
    
        var parcelOrdersWithNoteHistoryPoints = db.HistoryPoint.Where(hp => hp.Type == (int)HistoryPointType.Note)
            .Select(hp => hp.ParcelOrderID)
            .Distinct();

        Func<ParcelOrder, bool> completeExpression = order => userPrivilegeValidation(order) && criteriaMatchValidation(order);
        searchModel.PaginationTotalCount = db.ParcelOrder.Count(completeExpression);
       
        // todo: use this count for pagination
}


public Func<ParcelOrder, bool> CriteriaMatchValidationExpression(ParcelOrderSearchModel searchModel)
{
        Func<ParcelOrder, bool> expression =
            po => po.ID == 1;

        expression =
           po =>
           (searchModel.KeyUploadID == null || po.UploadID == searchModel.KeyUploadID)
       && (searchModel.KeyCustomerID == null || po.CustomerID == searchModel.KeyCustomerID)
       && (searchModel.KeyContainingVendorProvidedId == null || (po.VendorProvidedID != null && searchModel.KeyContainingVendorProvidedId.Contains(po.VendorProvidedID)))
       && (searchModel.ExactKeyReferenceNumber == null || (po.CustomerID + "-" + po.ReferenceNumber) == searchModel.ExactKeyReferenceNumber)
       && (searchModel.ExactKey_CrypticID == null || po.CrypticID == searchModel.ExactKey_CrypticID)
       && (searchModel.ContainsKey_ReferenceNumber == null || (po.CustomerID + "-" + po.ReferenceNumber).Contains(searchModel.ContainsKey_ReferenceNumber))
       && (searchModel.OrKey_Referencenumber_ConsignmentID == null ||
               ((po.CustomerID + "-" + po.ReferenceNumber).Contains(searchModel.OrKey_Referencenumber_ConsignmentID)
               || (po.VendorProvidedID != null && po.VendorProvidedID.Contains(searchModel.OrKey_Referencenumber_ConsignmentID))))
       && (searchModel.KeyClientName == null || po.Parcel.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchModel.KeyClientName.ToUpper()))
       && (searchModel.KeyCountries == null || searchModel.KeyCountries.Contains(po.Parcel.City.Country))
       && (searchModel.KeyOrderStates == null || searchModel.KeyOrderStates.Contains(po.State.Value))
       && (searchModel.KeyFromDateRegisteredToOTS == null || po.DateRegisteredToOTS > searchModel.KeyFromDateRegisteredToOTS)
       && (searchModel.KeyToDateRegisteredToOTS == null || po.DateRegisteredToOTS < searchModel.KeyToDateRegisteredToOTS)
       && (searchModel.KeyFromDateDeliveredToVendor == null || po.DateRegisteredToVendor > searchModel.KeyFromDateDeliveredToVendor)
       && (searchModel.KeyToDateDeliveredToVendor == null || po.DateRegisteredToVendor < searchModel.KeyToDateDeliveredToVendor);
        return expression;
}

public Func<ParcelOrder, bool> UserPrivilegeValdationExpression(string userId)
{
        var roles = GetRolesForUser(userId);

        Func<ParcelOrder, bool> expression =
            po => po.ID == 1;
        if (roles != null)
        {
            if (roles.Contains("ParcelAdministrator"))
                expression =
                    po => true;

            else if (roles.Contains("RegionalAdministrator"))
            {
                var user = db.AspNetUsers.First(u => u.Id == userId);
                if (user.RegionalAdministrator != null)
                {
                    expression =
                        po => po.HubID == user.RegionalAdministrator.HubID;
                }
            }
            else if (roles.Contains("Customer"))
            {
                var customerID = db.AspNetUsers.First(u => u.Id == userId).CustomerID;
                expression =
                    po => po.CustomerID == customerID;
            }
            else
            {
                expression =
                    po => false;
            }
        }

        return expression;
}
```

Comment: `.Count` should go all the way through to the database, so it's there that you will need to optimize. Given such a complex predicate (not really indexable, unless you can find a good filtering column, therefore it will prob be slow whatever you do) and such a large amount of rows, I would question the need for a count in the first place, especially if you are paginating. But please do share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com and maybe we can do something

Comment: It is important to note that this is technically NOT a discussion about EF, EF has simply made it easier for you to express your complicated query requirement. There are alternate solutions for this problem, such as writing an optimised SQL query to return the results (Bypass EF), using an external NO-SQL indexing service (Something like Azure Search Services), materialised views (or your own coded index). Azure search is awesome for this, but if you can re-structure the content into a form that simplifies the search process when the data is changed you can get better performance results.

Comment: To reiterate @Charlieface Knowing the total count is not all that useful for paging in itself, what you really need is the first or current page results. worst case scenario, load the total count asynchronously... This type of data scenario is exactly what external services like Azure Search are designed to solve for you.

Comment: Is `ParcelOrderSearchModel` a table, query, function or a view?

Comment: `ParcelOrderSearchModel`is not a database entity at all. It is a C# class that serves to encapsualte query parameters and is used by Service classes exclusively to call the `GetMatchingOrders` function. The count is needed in order to calculated the number of pages available and because the client needs the total number of records to show on the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can possibly avoid it, don't count for pagination.  Just return the first page.  It's always expensive to count and adds little to the user experience.

And in any case you're building the dynamic search wrong.

You're calling `IEnumerable.Count(Func<ParcelOrder,bool>)`, which will force client-side evaluation where you should be calling `IQueryable.Count(Expression<Func<ParcelOrder,bool>>)`.  Here:

```
    Func<ParcelOrder, bool> completeExpression = order => userPrivilegeValidation(order) && criteriaMatchValidation(order);
    searchModel.PaginationTotalCount = db.ParcelOrder.Count(completeExpression);
```

But there's a simpler, better pattern for this in EF: just conditionally add criteria to your IQueryable.

eg put a method on your DbContext like this:

```
public IQueryable<ParcelOrder> SearchParcels(ParcelOrderSearchModel searchModel)
{
        var q = this.ParcelOrders();
        if (searchModel.KeyUploadID != null)
        {
          q = q.Where( po => po.UploadID == searchModel.KeyUploadID );
        }
        if (searchModel.KeyCustomerID != null)
        {
          q = q.Where( po.CustomerID == searchModel.KeyCustomerID );
        }
        //. . .
        return q;
}
```

Comment: Fixing this obvious mistake (calling `Count()` on `IQueryable`rather than `ÌEnumerable`) speeds is up more than tenfold and solves the problem for us.

Comment: Conditionally setting the criteria, given that the criterion are generally exclusive can save the query a lot. It means that there will be different cached query plans, but that is usually OK in this scenario. Individual plans for the different types of lookups will see much simpler long term maintenance